# java.time - How to parse datetime format in various patterns (with ALL optional time components, except YEAR)?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I need to parse a String which represents  datetime to java 8 `DateTime` object to manipulate. For example, the valid strings are (**ALL datetime components (except year) are optional**):

```
2015
2015-01
2015-01-01
2015-02-03T00
2015-02-03T00:30
2015-02-03T00:30:50
2015-02-03T00:30:50Z
2015-02-03T00:30:50.333Z
2015-02-03T00:30:50.333+03:00
2015-02-03T00:30:50.333+0300
2015-02-03T00:30:50.333-08
2015-02-03T00:30:50.333GMT+8
2015-02-03GMT+8
2015-02UTC-3
2015-02PST
...
```

The best code (with my adjustments from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985789/2028440) which I've found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823661/2028440,

```
                DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
                .appendPattern("[['-']MM[['-']dd[['T']HH[[':']mm[[':']ss['.'SSS]]]]]][Z][O][VV]")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)
                .toFormatter();

        String[] s = {
                "2018",
                "2018-10",
                "2018-10-15",
                "2018-10-15T12:00",
                "2018-10-15T12:00:30",
                "2018-10-15T12:00:30.123Z",
                "2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-0800",
                "2018-10-15T12:00:30.123UTC-08:00",
                "2018-10-15T12:00:30.123GMT+9"
        };
        for (String line : s) {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(line, dtf));
        }
```

The console output is:

```
2018-01-01T00:00
2018-10-01T00:00
2018-10-15T00:00
2018-10-15T12:00
2018-10-15T12:00:30
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123
```

but it doesn't parse the time offset properly as the for the three last values it prints `2018-10-15T12:00:30.123`.

It should **print the correct time offset** for each of them as well.
Here are the correct outputs for the last 3 test strings:

```
"2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00"
"2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00"
"2018-10-15T12:00:30.123+09:00"
```

It is like the output from this command:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00").toString());

prints

2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00
```

When I tried to change from:

```
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(line, dtf));
```

to:

```
            System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(line, dtf));
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2018-01-01T00:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:598)
```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it doesn't matter if it is not 100% valid. I just need it parsed to DateTime object.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I removed the word ISO format from the title and content, as my examples are flexible and not stricly valid to the standard

Comment: then my comments no longer apply.

Comment: Can you show what the correct outputs are, for the three last values?

Comment: @Sweeper Here are the correct outputs with timeoffsets

"2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00",
"2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00",
"2018-10-15T12:00:30.123+09:00"

It is like the output from this command:         System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00").toString());

Comment: This one seems to fit, not perfectly, but pretty well: [More beautiful Multiple DateTimeFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334271/more-beautiful-multiple-datetimeformatter). Does it answer your question?

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for providing a reference, I got the answer for datetime parsing already from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815456/parsing-an-iso-8601-date-in-java8-when-all-fields-including-separators-but-not/52823661#52823661

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `LocalDateTime.parse`, so of course only the local date time part of the string is outputted.

When you use `ZonedDateTime.parse`, some of the strings cannot be parsed because there is no offset or zone information. We can partially solve this by adding a

```
.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
```

However, this will not handle the cases when there is only timezone, but not offset information. (Note that "UTC-08:00" in "2018-10-15T12:00:30.123UTC-08:00" is considered a timezone ID) Such strings are actually ambiguous -  just having a timezone and a local date time is sometimes not enough to make a `ZonedDateTime` in an "overlap" timezone transition. The same local date time would happen twice, at different offsets. You would have to make a decision as to which one you choose.

So rather than using `parseDefaulting` also on the offset, directly use `dtf.parse(line)` and query on the `TemporalAccessor` you get. There are 3 cases:

- the temporal accessor has offset information, use that offset to make a `ZonedDateTime`
- the temporal accessor only has timezone information, use that timezone to make a `ZonedDateTime`, and remember to make a decision on which one to choose in case of an overlap transition
- the temporal accessor has neither offset nor timezone information. Use UTC as the zone to make a `ZonedDateTime`.

You could also add a fourth case to handle when there is both offset and timezone information in the string and use both to create a `ZonedDateTime`, if needed.

```
var accessor = dtf.parse(line);
var zone = accessor.query(TemporalQueries.zone());
var offset = accessor.query(TemporalQueries.offset());
var ldt = LocalDateTime.from(accessor);
if (offset != null) {
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, offset));
} else if (zone != null) {
    // this chooses the earlier time in an overlap
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, zone));

    // more generally...
//    var transition = zone.getRules().getTransition(ldt);
//    if (transition != null && transition.isOverlap()) {
//        ZonedDateTime.ofLocal(
//                ldt, zone, 
//                transition.getOffsetAfter() // or getOffsetBefore()
//        );
//    }
} else {
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneOffset.UTC));
}
```

The above outputs:

```
2018-01-01T00:00Z
2018-10-01T00:00Z
2018-10-15T00:00Z
2018-10-15T12:00Z
2018-10-15T12:00:30Z
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123Z
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123-08:00[UTC-08:00]
2018-10-15T12:00:30.123+09:00
```

If you don't want the `[UTC-08:00]` timezone ID, use `toOffsetDateTime` to get a `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I could not be familiar with advanced feature in java.time java 8 without your help